# Take previous row with conditional in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How would you do this in numpy, without using a `for`-loop or `while`-loop, and if it is possible, using the fastest way to do it in terms of execution time.

It is something like "if the value in an specific column and row is higher than 20  assign the previous value".

(I'm using the column 2 for this case)

```
a = np.random.randint(1,50, size=(10,5))

print(a)
print('--------------')

for index in range(len(a)):
       
    if (a[index][2] > 20) and index>0:
        
        a[index][2]=a[index-1][2]

print(a)


[[21 24 | 7| 10 12]
 [ 4 36 |42|  4 48]
 [37 43 |36| 30 13]
 [39 10 |45| 45 15]
 [46 48 |25| 39 20]
 [ 2 33 |37| 38 28]
 [23 36 |14| 29 33]
 [17 24 |47|  4  9]
 [45  9 |42| 34  3]
 [13 49 |26| 14 34]]
--------------
[[21 24 | 7| 10 12]
 [ 4 36 | 7|  4 48]
 [37 43 | 7| 30 13]
 [39 10 | 7| 45 15]
 [46 48 | 7| 39 20]
 [ 2 33 | 7| 38 28]
 [23 36 |14| 29 33]
 [17 24 |14|  4  9]
 [45  9 |14| 34  3]
 [13 49 |14| 14 34]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since values are repetitive, you can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
arr = a[:, 2]

cutoff_idx = np.flatnonzero(arr<=20)
vals = arr[cutoff_idx]
counts = np.diff(cutoff_idx, append=len(arr))

if len(cutoff_idx) > 0:
    n = cutoff_idx[0]
    a[:n, 2] = arr[:n] #this is a custom approach since there's no info
    a[n:, 2] = np.repeat(vals, counts)
```

Comment: What if `a[:,2]` starts with more than one value `>20`?

Comment: It returns a `ValueError`. I am about to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Replace your `if`, `else` with the following three (unconditional) statements: `n = cutoff_idx[0]` then `a[n:, 2] = np.repeat(vals, counts)` then `a[:n, 2] = np.repeat(a[0,2], n)`

Comment: There might still be an edge-case if `cutoff_idx` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the result:

```
spec_col = a[:, 2]
cond = np.where(spec_col <= 20)[0]
diff = np.diff(cond, append=len(spec_col))
cond_vals = np.take(spec_col, cond)
repeated_arr = np.repeat(cond_vals, diff)
spec_col[np.where(spec_col <= 20)[0][0]:] = repeated_arr
print(a)
```

It will get stuck if there not be any `values <= 20` in the **spec_col**, duo to `np.where` nature, which can be handled easily by `try-except` method:

```
try:
    spec_col = a[:, 2]
    cond = np.where(spec_col <= 20)[0]
    diff = np.diff(cond, append=len(spec_col))
    cond_vals = np.take(spec_col, cond)
    repeated_arr = np.repeat(cond_vals, diff)
    spec_col[np.where(spec_col <= 20)[0][0]:] = repeated_arr
    print(a)

except:
    a[:, 2] = a[0, 2]       # or any values
    print(a)
```

By this additional method, you can handle such this condition; e.g. if `a` array be as:

```
a = np.array([[7,  8 , 40 , 6 , 38],
              [35, 35, 22 , 16, 25],
              [39, 7 , 66 , 31, 37],
              [40, 31, 33 , 4 , 12],
              [49, 21, 118, 39, 12],
              [48, 38, 216, 34, 9 ],
              [11, 32, 22 , 34, 3 ],
              [22, 26, 47 , 10, 48],
              [44, 19, 34 , 44, 22],
              [39, 37, 42 , 41, 27]])
```

The specified column is `[40 22 66 33 118 216 22 47 34 42]`, and by the written `except` it will change all the values to *the first value* (which can be specified to be something else in the `except` part) i.e. `40` as `[40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40]`.